# git pull already up to date but head is not detached

Tags: git, github, git-pull

Reading the title I know you would be pretty shocked as in why I am sure about head not being detached. I am not very used to GIT. There has been a change in the original repo I have made my clone from named upstream. I am trying to pull those changes by git pull, which says, Already up to date.
I did,

```
git branch -r

origin/HEAD -> origin/master
origin/master
upstream/branchName
upstream/master
```

So my head is at origin master, which I think is fine.
And doing,

```
cat .git/HEAD
```

gives

```
ref: refs/heads/master
```

All over Stack I see people referring it to a detached head problem. But I think that's not the case with me.
I had done a git fetch upstream yesterday which showed me compressing files and everything. But when I opened the repo in my editor I dont see any new changes fetched.

Comment: Can you show result of `git remote -v` and `git branch -vva`

Comment: What is the question here? Please edit your post so it actually asks a question.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the meaning of a *detached head*. As you can see, `.git/HEAD` refers to the head of your `master` branch, and thus, by definition, is not *detached*. If it were detached, it would refer to another commit that is not a branch head.

Comment: Also, "detached head" has very little to do with what you are writing about. You are probably confused as to what it means. Read e.g. http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout (section "DETACHED HEAD") for more information.

Comment: @pktangyue origin https://github.com/myName/repoName.git (fetch)
origin https://github.com/myName/repoName.git (push)
upstream https://github.com/OriginalMastersName/repoName.git (fetch)
upstream https://github.com/originalMastersName/repoName.git (push)

Comment: @sleske The third line in my question is the question.Pretty funny, you couldn't understand it.

Comment: @dibs_ab: Sorry, I don't see a question; questions usually have question marks :-). Anyway, your problem is fixed, so I guess it's a moot point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git fetch` fetches the commits but does not affect your `HEAD` position. You need to merge your local master with the upstream you want:
`git merge upstream/master` (or `git merge origin/master`).

`git pull` normally does both `git fetch` and `git merge` for you, but it will abort if there is no new commits. Note that if you pull from other remotes like your `upstream`, you need to specify it, together with the branch to merge with: `git pull upstream master`

Comment: I got all the files in my local after I did git merge upstream/master. It should affect my repo at github too right? The commit it lasts shows is not the latest one updated.

Comment: Do comment if you know the reason to why it did not update my repo on github but updated on my local copy on my pc. Strange.

Comment: I solved it by doing `git push origin master` Not a right way, but solved my problem. Do let me know if you know the reason to this @tapio

Comment: @dibs_ab: All git actions apart from push and pull (and their friends such as fetch) operate solely on your local repo, offline. That's the beauty of distributed version control systems - no network access or latency on stuff like merge, log and diff. So your `git push` is in fact the correct way to sync to github.